# JavaScript and HTML element manipulation

Tags: javascript, php, html, for-loop

Project Concept: Creating an "exam maker", which can be accessed by a teacher to create and let a student be able to access it to take. Many features would be included but to keep it simple on the question at hand i wont be including all info.

Front End: List all questions in the database, using a php file, to a select field in HTML. When the item is selected add it to the test. Display the test, and assign scoring to each question.

My Actual Question/Help: My addq() function is supposed to, get the value of selected item, append it on the global testArray=[]; while the for loop iterates through each one to display them individually after each one is added.

The Problem: What mine is displaying in HTML... it keeps adding the arrays so the output is repeated over and over after each addq(). Please help fix it! -- the array needs to be outside the function so I can access it later and send it off to a php file.

```
<h4><center>Test</center></h4>
 <ol id="test">
</ol>



<script>

var testArray= [];

function addq(){

     var addingquestion = document.getElementById('questionSelect').value;
     var myArray = testArray.push(addingquestion);
     var node = document.createElement("LI");

     for(i=0;i<20;i++){

     var textnode = document.createTextNode(testArray[i].toString());
     node.appendChild(textnode);
     document.getElementById("test").appendChild(node);
      }
    }
</script>
```

Example Output Issue Picture:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fuUsR.png)

Comment: because you make one li and keep adding the text to it.... You need a new li on every iteration.

Comment: if i move the "li" into the loop it will keep adding extra elements... where am i going wrong? @epascarello

Comment: That is what I assumed you wanted....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem is that you're appending the array every time to the node element. So, every time it will output the old values with the new ones

You don't have to make it as an array because it stacks without an array,

you just need to replace this :

```
 var textnode = document.createTextNode(testArray[i].toString());
```

with this :

```
 var textnode = document.createTextNode(addingquestion);
```

Comment: that is so much simpler.. woops!  I was wondering if you can add a textbox to each question that can be filled out and data passed to a php file. 

For example ... itll list "question 1" [textbox1]  "question2"[textbox2] ..etc.

Unsure how to add a Textbox to each question submitted, Id appreciate any help with that!!

Comment: It depends on what you're trying to do exactly

Comment: so the goal is to .. Add Question to be displayed. (which was successfully done) .. give each question a text box to be a lotted scores. 

question1 = 10pts . etc like a normal exam.

then take the information, question and the scores... to send them off. Is that enough info to get advice?

Comment: I'm not very good at back-end, but I think I can help

Here you will need to create a table in the database called "text" for example. Make a relation between it and the questions table, after adding the questions,
you may redirect the user to a page where he can add a text for every question they've added...

for example after adding 3 questions,
get the questions from the database and connect them with the text table when saving..

question 1: <TEXTBOX>
question 2: <TEXTBOX>
question 3: <TEXTBOX>

<SAVE>

Comment: You must make sure that the 2 tables are connecting with each others through the ID

the questions must have an id column
and the texts must have a column named question_id for example

hope that helps :)

Comment: Oh sorry, I guess I didn't explain as well as i should have. The backend stuff I don't actually have to worry about.. I just need to know how-to give each question a text box so I can save the information in an array... I dont know how to add a text box using javascript..... so i wanted a textbox to "appear" everytime I added a question so it can be filled out. -- (i have group members.. Im front-end .. they are middle/back, if that gives any clarification)

Comment: https://gyazo.com/d717b51b657a00a9fc329afec2914adc

here is what I mean if it makes it easier visually!

Comment: document.getElementById("test").innerHTML = document.getElementById("test").innerHTML + "<input type='text' value='' >";

Comment: just add this at the end of the loop

Answer (score 0):

Here, you need to be creating you LI each time, it is an object.

```js
var testArray = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10];

function addq() {
  // REMOVED because not provided.
  //let addingquestion = document.getElementById('questionSelect').value;
  //let myArray = testArray.push(addingquestion);
  let test = document.querySelector('#test');

  testArray.forEach(t => {
    // create new li for each item.
    let li = document.createElement('li');
    let textnode = document.createTextNode(t);
    li.appendChild(textnode);
    test.appendChild(li);
  });
}

addq();
```

```html
<h4>
  <center>Test</center>
</h4>
<ol id="test">
</ol>
```

Comment: The problem here is that he is running the function every time the user choose a value without deleting the old values, so first time it's question 1, second time it's question1 + question1 & question2 and so on...

Comment: Ah, gotcha. Thanks @MohamedAshraf